# nmcli command takes only first string of ssid?

Tags: shell, command-line, wifi, nmcli

The below `nmcli` command to connect to WiFi doesn't connect if it has more than one word as **ssid name**?

```
nmcli device wifi connect my homewifi password mypass
```

NOTE:

```
SSID name: my homewifi (bad since is has 2 words)
SSID name: my (good since only has 1 word)
```

Connecting with one word ssid name is good, but multiple word is bad, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are spaces in the command line, you should use quotes:

```
nmcli device wifi connect "my homewifi" password mypass
```

This will let the shell and `nmcli` know that this is to be considered as one word.

Comment: Can you show how to call this from bash? "${ssid}" not working for me.

Comment: Put echo in front of the command to better see what is being generated